# NotCompressibleException при попытке закриптовать скомпилированный файл .bat через BatToExeConverver в UPX

Tags: windows, exe, bat

Размер файла - 9,17 МБ (9 622 528 байт).
При попытке крипта файла через UPX вылезает NotCompressibleException. Как это решить?

Comment: Возможно ваш экзешник уже сжат с помощью UPX или другого "сжимателя".

Comment: @insolor нет, с помощью Resource Hacker удается просмотреть ресурсы.

Comment: Это ни о чем не говорит. Нужно смотреть чем-то типа PEiD, я бы вообще тупо в иду загнал - если есть большие блоки "мусора", который не дизассмеблируются нормально, значит код пожат (скорее всего) .